# MySQL query for selecting multiple rows as arrays of those rows data

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to select frist 3 rows and after that next 3 ( offset 3 ) and get the result as two arrays in a single query ? Something like:

```
(SELECT * FROM product WHERE 1 LIMIT 3) as first_array
(SELECT * FROM product WHERE 1 OFFSET 3 LIMIT 3) as second_array
```

Hope you understand me. Sorry about the explanation just dont't know how to explain in other way.

Lets say I only want the ids - output example:

```
id_1   id_2
 1       4
 2       5
 3       6
```

What I have tried from the answers below the post is :

```
SELECT id as id_1 FROM `ct_product` WHERE 1 LIMIT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT id as id_2 FROM `ct_product` WHERE 1 LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3
```

The result is strange for me. It seems it returns only the second query results and they are not the 4th 5th and 6th row but the 5th 6th and 3th (in this order).
My table rows are:

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: What do you mean by "arrays"? MySQL doesn't have array variables.

Comment: Just to group it. Gave it alias for more than one result - result_1 ( id, name) / result_2 (id, name) where the result_1 have to hold the data of the first group of 
 products anb result_2 - the second group of products.

Comment: You might want to use temporary tables for that.

Comment: as i getting your requirement you can use union to combine your both condition in a single query

Comment: Please give an example of how your results output should look like.

Comment: I edited the questin with output example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with this query:

```
SELECT a1.id, a2.id
FROM (SELECT *, @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 AS rownum
      FROM (SELECT id
            FROM `ct_product`
            LIMIT 3
            ) art
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) r
      ) a1
JOIN  (SELECT *, @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 AS rownum
      FROM (SELECT id
            FROM `ct_product`
            LIMIT 3, 3
            ) art
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
      ) a2
ON a1.rownum = a2.rownum
```

Output:

```
id  id  
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

This query works by creating two new tables with artificially generated row numbers (`@rownum1` and `@rownum2`) from the first 3 and the second 3 rows in the original table. They are then JOINed on matching row numbers to get the desired result.